# Workflow if else condition for field update

Tags: workflow

I want to write a work flow with this condition.

```
if(field_A > field_B)     field_C == 'Success';
else (field_A < field_B)  field_C == 'Fail';
```

field_C is a picklist field. is this possible to archive using single work flow. else do I need to write 2 workflows. Or is their any other way to achieve it without trigger.

Comment: try with process builder... you can add multiple logic in process builder

Comment: You could do this with CASE